# multiprocessing in python, OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm testing out the multiprocessing Manager package in python 2.7 and running into a problem that has already been documented for NFS running with Unix (https://bugs.python.org/issue13978). The problem is whilst this highlights the problem, it's not clear to me how you get around this problem, or what the alternative is?

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Manager()
```

I then call my script and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 274, in 
_run_finalizers
finalizer()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 207, in __call__
res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/home/user/.tmp/pymp-xrl_Vc/.nfs0000000196'
```

If I can't use the Manager is there another way I can share an object between multiple processes, or is there a workaround (suggested method of manager.shutdown and del manager don't have any effect)?

Had some more time to look at this today and after some digging I've found a solution that leads to a clean exit (i.e. no errors).

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
mp = Manager()
mp.shutdown()
#results in the above error

mp = Manager()
mp._process.terminate()
mp.shutdown()
#shutdown complete without any errors
```

I'm not very clear why this works though or if it's a sensible thing to do